# Coffeescript to manipulate DOM with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, coffeescript

I want to add a row in a table based on an an existing row.
I am trying to do it with coffeescript -- but it just doesn't work.

I think I am misunderstanding the way the insertion works in the nested div fields . .because I can move the elements around if they don't have any lower level components ..

So if you can see what I am doing wrong -- please advise and I would also appreciate if you can throw a line on how to change the ID of the added element  ..

Here is the coffeescript and the html

```js
$(".add_row").click ->
 jQuery ->
     $("#row1").clone().appendTo($("#row3"))
 alert "Done"
```

```html
<table>
  <div id="row1">
    <tr>       <td> r1c1 </td>       <td> r1c2</td>     </tr>
  </div>
  <div id="row2">
    <tr>       <td> r2c1</td>      <td> r2c2 </td>     </tr>
  </div>
  <div id="row3">
    <tr>     <td> r3c1 </td>       <td> r3c2</td>     </tr>
  </div>
  <tr>
    <td>-</td>   <td> <button class="add_row"> Add Another Row </button> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is not valid so the browser will probably rewrite it and throw everything off for you.

From the [fine specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/table.html#table-content-model):

> **Permitted contents**
>   An optional `caption` element, followed by zero or more `colgroup` elements, followed by an optional `thead` element, followed by
>
> > one `tfoot` element, followed by zero or more `tbody` elements, or one or more `tr` elements
>
> **or**
>
> > zero or more `tbody` elements, or one or more `tr` elements
> >     followed by an optional `tfoot` element

In particular, `<table><div>` is not valid. When your jQuery gets to work with the `<table>`, `#row1` won't be inside the table at all and it might not contain what you're expecting it to.

Valid HTML is important so fix the HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr id="row1">
    <td> r1c1 </td>
    <td> r1c2 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row2">
    <td> r2c1 </td>
    <td> r2c2 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row3">
    <td> r3c1 </td>
    <td> r3c2 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>-</td>
    <td> <button class="add_row"> Add Another Row </button> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then you'll want to fix up your CoffeeScripts. First the indentation, that needs to be consistent and correct since indentation defines the structure of your CoffeeScript. Also, the inner `jQuery ->` call is unnecessary, that's used to queue up a function to call when the document is ready to work with but you just want to run a bit of code right now when the button is clicked. Furthermore, you don't want to use [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) as that will:

> Insert every element in the set of matched elements to the end of the target.

where you want to put the cloned row *after* `#row3`, not inside it. You'd be better off using [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) and starting with `#row3` like this:

```
$(".add_row").click ->
    $('#row3').after($('#row1').clone())
```

This will still leave you with some problems, in particular:

1. You'll have duplicate `#row1` elements.
2. Hitting the button again will keep adding new rows after `#row3` rather than right above the button row.

I'll leave fixing those as an exercise for the reader.

For example: https://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ksndgdpa/

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the div inside the table issue at all  -- thank for the complete answer  -- I learnt three things from it!